# What do you call unity gain? 1V/V or 1V/V plus a small tolerance?

Tags: operational-amplifier, unity-gain

I designed a two stage single ended op amp with an internal frequency compensation. There's a minor problem that I noticed in my loop gain transfer function.

I forced the gain to reduce to around 0.5dB at fz1=200MHz, where fz1 is an LHP zero. In addition to fz1 I've got a pair of complex conjugate poles at about 400MHz. Think of complex conjugate poles as two real poles that merge together. The other poles and zeros are not important so forget about them.

The problem is that the gain is almost constant, starting at 200MHz with the magnitude ~0.5dB and slowly decreasing (due to the nearside complex conjugate poles) to 0dB at 250MHz, which is considered to be the unity gain frequency of my op amp.

**So now is the unity gain really at 250MHz? Because the gain is almost 1.05V/V at 200MHz where 1.05V/V is only 5% greater than the unity gain.** Maybe it depends on the application and the precision that it requires.But anyway please let me know if my design is any good.

Thanks

Comment: There is no right or wrong. There is just whether it is good enough for a particular application or not. The way I would describe it is that the gain flatness is 0.5dB from 200 MHz to 250 MHz. I am sure that would be very useful for many applications.

Comment: @mkeith great comment, that cleared up my confusion. However the gain is not that flat, it changes from 0.5dB at 200MHz to 0dB at 250MHz. It means that at 230MHz, for example, the gain flatness is only 0.285dB which per your opinion it can be still fine

Comment: Gain is never perfectly flat. Flatness is the specification telling you how much variation in gain there is in a certain band. So, in the band from 200 to 250 MHz, the flatness is 0.5dB. https://www.empowerrf.com/rf-amplifiers/index.php?topic=passband_fr

Comment: Just google "gain flatness".

Comment: @mkeith Yes, sure. Actually gain flatness is not an issue here. I was only care about whether there might be any distinction between 0.5dB and 0dB because 0.5dB is too close to unity gain.

Comment: And actually gain flatness around 0.5dB first looked a bit unappealing to me. Now it seems that the actual dB level may or may not become serious depending on the target application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In engineering or science speak unity gain is 0.0000000'db.

Get your head out of your theoretical cloud. You need to decide in terms of how you are applying this where close enough to 0db is good enough.